# Showing that a polynomial is surjective

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

How do I formally show that a polynomial, say $f(x)=x^3 - 5$, is surjective? For example, if $f(x)$ were a linear function such as $f(x) = 5x$, then I would simple need to show that for all $y$ in the range, there is an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ and I would choose that $x = y/5$. My intuition tells me that it has something do with the fact that polynomials are continuous, i.e. that all of their range of $\mathbb{R}$ is mapped to by $f(x)$. Please guide me as to how to formally prove this for any polynomials of odd degree $\geq 3$.

Comment: If you're happy with $5x \leftrightarrow y/5$, then why not $x^3 \leftrightarrow \sqrt[3]{y}$? But as for _"prove this for any or all polynomials with degree ≥2"_, the even powered polynomials $x^{2k}$ are not surjective (in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @StackTD My bad, let me change that.

Comment: Yes $f(x)=x^3$ is continuous, and while perhaps useful information, far more useful of information is that $f(x)$ has only one real root and that $f'(x)$ is strictly non-negative.  Any polynomial (from reals to reals) who has only one real root and whose derivative is strictly non-negative (or whose derivative is strictly non-positive) will be bijective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is continuous, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}x^3=+\infty\;,\;\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}x^3=-\infty$

There exists $a,b$ such that $f(a)<-N, f(b)>N$, $f([a,b])$ is an interval which contains $[-N,N]$